# logstash-filter-useragent plugin identifies new Edge as Chrome

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I'm on the latest version of logstash-filter-useragent.
I have the following UA `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.52`

This UA comes from Microsoft's Edge browser (the Chromium based one).
The expected Output for the name field is `Edge 87.0`. However, I get `Chrome 87.0` instead.

From what I see, logstash-filter-useragent was lastly updated in 2019.
Is there a different plugin I can use or a simple fix to I can implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage the regexes.yaml separately from the user_agent plugin, just as you would manage the geoip database separately from the geoip plugin. The latest regexes.yaml can be found in [this](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core) github project.